# Can installing Ubuntu cause Windows to run hot on dual boot machine?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, hardware, overheating, temperature

Okay, I'm pretty sure that it is not possible for Ubuntu to cause hardware problems with Windows but..

I installed 12.04 as a dual boot on a Compaq Presario CQ61 running Windows 7 Home premium. Install ran flawlessly and dual boot works fine. Like many other people, I noticed my machine ran very hot when using Ubuntu. Weird part is it now also seems to be running hotter when I'm in Windows. Common sense and what little I know about computers tells me that there couldn't possibly be a connection but I want to check with the community just in case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 2):

#### Not possible

But, if you reboot into Windows right after you've been on Ubuntu, things may seem hotter while the "extra" heat dissipates. This should disappear if you "cold boot" Windows after your computer has been off for at least one hour.

Needless to say, directly rebooting is not going to harm your computer (though your lap may feel warmer ;)